# Contrapositive of "if $x$ is a real number"

Tags: logic

Write the contrapositive of the following statement: If $x$ is a real number, then
$$
x^2 ≥ 0
$$

Comment: The contrapositive of "If P, then Q" is "If not Q, then not P". In your case Q is $x^2\geq 0$. So, "not Q" is "$x^2<0$ or $x^2$ is not comparable to $0$". In your case P is "$x$ is a real number". So "not P" is "$x$ is not a real number".

Answer (score 2):

If $x^2$ is not larger or equal to $0$, then $x$ is not a real number.

Comment: This is the proper counterpositive.

Answer (score 1):

If $x^2\not\geq0$ then $x$ is not a real number.

Comment: @orole thanks for the correction.

Comment: No problem. Now it is good

Answer (score 1):

$x^2\not \ge 0\implies $ $x $ is not a real number...

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not the full counterpositive.

Comment: It appears to be:  the contrapositive of $a\implies b $ is $-b\implies -a $...

Comment: The negation of $x^2\geq0$ is not just $x^2<0$. There is a case missing.

Comment: Yes, I would need $x^2\not\ge 0$...  you're right. ..

Answer (score 1):

You stated:
$$x\in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow x^2\geq 0$$

Thus the counterpositive is:
$$x^2 \not\geq 0 \Rightarrow x\not\in \mathbb{R}$$